# Laravel query different result between (identical?) two vs three argument 'where' clause

Tags: laravel, where-clause, laravel-query-builder

I'm having a very odd issue with a query in laravel (5.2) - I've got a collection created from some external source (an API), and I'm trying to run a 'where' query to extract specific records.

Originally, I was trying to extract all entries which were submitted during the current month (so, after the first day of this month)

```
$entries is the starting collection (time entries on a project - see end of post)

$thisMonthStart = (new Carbon('first day of this month'))->toDateString();
  //value of this is 2017-02-01, and the issue is not resolved if I remove toDateString()

$entriesThisMonth = $entries->where('spent-at', '>', $thisMonthStart); 
  //returns an empty collection, but should have 15 results
```

Now the really odd part, is that I tried instead to get $entries where 'spent-at' is *equal to* the first day of the month - there should be one entry.  If I *don't* explicitly specify the comparison operator, I get my expected result:

```
$entriesThisMonth = $entries->where('spent-at', $thisMonthStart);
  //one $entries returned, see end of post
```

However if I specify the = operator

```
$entriesThisMonth = $entries->where('spent-at', '=', $thisMonthStart);
  //empty collection returned
```

So I'm now very confused - presumably something is wrong in my original collection, but why does the specifying vs not specifying the operator make any difference?  I would have thought that those two queries would give identical results?

(and obviously, not being able to specify the operator is not very helpful when trying to do a < or > comparison, but I'm mostly just interested in what the actual difference is between those two syntaxes, and so why they give different results?)

I couldn't find any info anywhere on how these two versions of the query work and so if it's expected that they could give different results - I would think that they should be identical, but maybe someone with a deeper understanding could explain what's causing this?

Thank you to anyone who can shed some light on the mystery!

---

A sample of the $entries collection in case is of any use (just a single record):
(NB there are definitely records from the current month, I know this example is too old)

```
Collection {#952 ▼
  #items: array:367 [▼
175412141 => DayEntry {#958 ▼
  #_root: "request"
  #_convert: true
  #_values: array:16 [ …16]
  +"id": "175412141"
  +"notes": ""
  +"spent-at": "2013-10-03"
  +"hours": "0.75"
  +"user-id": "595841"
  +"project-id": "4287629"
  +"task-id": "2448666"
  +"created-at": "2013-10-03T18:07:54Z"
  +"updated-at": "2013-11-01T12:50:51Z"
  +"adjustment-record": "false"
  +"timer-started-at": ""
  +"is-closed": "false"
  +"is-billed": "true"
  +"started-at": "10:45"
  +"ended-at": "11:30"
  +"invoice-id": "3633772"
}
```

And this is what is returned by the where query *without* the operator:

```
Collection {#954 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
568944822 => DayEntry {#1310 ▼
  #_root: "request"
  #_convert: true
  #_values: array:15 [▶]
  +"id": "568944822"
  +"notes": "Tweaking formatting on job ads and re shuffling ad order"
  +"spent-at": "2017-02-01"
  +"hours": "0.25"
  +"user-id": "595841"
  +"project-id": "4287629"
  +"task-id": "2448666"
  +"created-at": "2017-02-01T14:45:00Z"
  +"updated-at": "2017-02-01T14:45:00Z"
  +"adjustment-record": "false"
  +"timer-started-at": ""
  +"is-closed": "false"
  +"is-billed": "false"
  +"started-at": "14:30"
  +"ended-at": "14:45"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `illuminate\Support\Collection::where` is different to the database collection where, it doesn't take an operator as the second argument.

The `where` method signature to the collection object you are working with is `where(string $key, mixed $value, bool $strict = true)`

Your second example with the operator is looking for all elements in the collection that match the string `'='`.

For further reading on the collection you are working with (not an eloquent collection) look [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)

To get the 15 results that you are expecting, use the `filter` method on the collection.

Something along these lines should work:

```
$entriesThisMonth = $entries->filter (function ($e) use ($thisMonthStart) {

    return $e ['spent-at'] > $thisMonthStart;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution and also the explanation and link - I didn't realise the where method was different between the two so I'll give that a proper read!  
I slightly modified your code to get it working as laravel throws an error using the array notation for $entries, and added >=, but pretty much spot on, thank you! :) 

`$entriesThisMonth = $entries->filter(function($i) use ($thisMonthStart){
                
                return $i->{"spent-at"} >= $thisMonthStart;
            });`

Answer (score 3):

***To fix your issue...*** "returns an empty collection, but should have 15 results". If the collection already exists, you need to `filter` the results. Something like so:

```
$thisMonthStart = new Carbon('first day of this month');

$entriesThisMonth = $entries->filter(function ($entry) use ($thisMonthStart) {
    return $entry['spent-at'] >= $thisMonthStart;
});
```

Comment: The get method on an object of type `Illuminate/Support/Collection` simply retrieves an element from the collection by key, and requires the key of the item to return to be passed as an argument in order to work. That example above will not work

Comment: Receives an element by key? Well, yeah. `get()` returns a collection. Above code will work to solve his issue "should have 15".

Comment: Just noticed, if the `$entries` collection already exists, you're right. He'd need to `filter` the results.

Comment: yeah, he says the collection is generated from an API so it's unlikely to be an eloquent collection. 

`$entriesThisMonth = $entries->filter (function ($e) use ($thisMonthStart) {

 return $e ['spent-at'] > $thisMonthStart;

});`

is the right way to get the expected 15 results I think.

Comment: As Keir correctly guessed, unfortunately it's not an eloquent collection so get() doesn't work - but the filter option does work, so thank you (and also Kier above) for that!  I'm going to accept Kier's answer as theirs goes into more depth on the distinction between the different where queries, but thank you also! :)

Comment: Sure thing. +1 me though and I would be grateful, especially since Keir rolled with my `filter` idea lol ;p

Comment: standing on the shoulders of giants.. :p Removed my -1 as your answer is now correct too